# Naming multiple variables for later use in a function

Tags: php, function, variables, configuration-files

My function must process a very large number of variables (20+). Since the number is growing unwieldy, I'm seeking an improvement over the traditional declaration of every single active variable each time I must call the function, like when:
     `MyFunction($var1,$var2,$var3,$var4,$var5,$var6,$var7,$var8,$var9,$var10......);`

I'm trying to write better, modular code that I can effectively re-use. As an improvement, is there a way to collapse the names of these many vars into a separate "config file," so that I can more cleanly call this function whenever needed...such as?
[within a separate config file:]
`$AllOfMyVariables = 'var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9,var10';`

...and then simply calling:  `MyFunction($AllOfMyVariables);`  whenever needed?

I've been unable to successfully do this.  I've tried passing the variable names via curly brackets, but can't seem to get the variable names/values to pass correctly.  Any suggestions?

Comment: you could create an array, and parse that

Comment: Okay. Could it live in a separate config file that could be used over-and-over?...or, would the array have to be re-created directly before calling the function each time?

Comment: yes it could, and no it wouldn't need to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare all of your config variables in an array like this with the keys being the variable name and the values being the variable's value.

```
$AllOfMyVariables = array(
  'var1' => 'value1',
  'var2' => 'value2',
  'var3' => 'vaule3');
```

That array can be stored in a separate PHP file if you like and then be `require()`'ed when you need it. Then you can pass this array into your function and use the extract function.

```
function MyFunction($AllOfMyVariables) {
    extract($AllOfMyVariables);
//Do ALL the things!
}
```

Now $var1 = 'value1', etc.

Comment: I like this idea, but I don't quite understand: Since the values of each of the variables are changing during the course of the script (perhaps just before I call the function), how can I have correctly "pre-inserted" the various values into the array which lives elsewhere?  Perhaps when I create the array, can I replace 'value1' with '$value1' (note the '$'), so that it stays "dynamic"?

Comment: Yes, you can modify the base array later. You start off with the array containing the preset values and then you can modify it by using `$AllOfMyVariables['variable_name'] = 'variable value';`.  (Edit: Do this before the call to `extract()`.)

Comment: I can modify the array as you suggest before calling the function? or, within the function (but before calling extract)?

Comment: You can modify it anywhere between where you originally declare it (if you're keeping it in a separate php file then any time after the `require()` call) and where it's passed into the `extract()` function. Either inside or outside the function doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities, the first one mentioned by user1612290.

The second one is to use array of parameters, like

```
$arr = array($var1, $var2, ...);
```

or

```
$arr = array('var1' => $var1, 'var2' => $var2, ...);
```

and call the function by

```
MyFunction($arr);
```

The similar way is to use an object instead, so

```
$object = new stdClass;
$object->var1 = $var1; // and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use an array, in PHP you can add a indeterminate number of values in an array

```
$param[0]="zero";
$param[1]="one";
```

......

You can call your function:

```
MyFunction($param);
```

And you can go all the array:

```
foreach($param as $key => $value)
```

The key of array is in $value and the value is in $param[$key]